# Simplifying URL without using .htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, url

How to modify URL such ***www.mysite.com/dir.php?ID=123***

to ***www.mysite.com/dir/123*** without using or involving ***.htaccess***

cause I can't access ***.htaccess*** on our server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** this is your own application and not the standard framework/CMS then you can implement your own rewrite engine in PHP so the URLs would look like `www.mysite.com/index.php/dir/123`.
That's slightly worse than the clean URLs but that's the best you can achieve.

When you run the url like that the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` PHP variable would store "`/dir/123`" which is then your job to parse and transform to the params you need and then invoke or include the right script.

IIRC [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls) is built like that. So you can look their code for an inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option is using a [rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) on the web server software, e. g. mod_rewrite for [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

But as long as you don't even control files on your server, you probably don't have access to Apache configuration.

Your web app/CMS should have support for nice URLs too.

Comment: If OP doesn't even have permission to create `.htaccess` files, I doubt they will have permission to freely modify the `http.conf` which would be required to configure mod_rewrite without a htaccess.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i had pointed out in the first place (line 2).

Answer (score 0):

Short story is:

**You can't**

At least you should be able to use `.htaccess` to normally do this. If you can't even use that, other options will most probably also be limited out for you.

But there is one work-around that you MAYBE (I'm absolutely not sure) can use...

Are you allowed to set your own 404 error pages?

If so, try setting a `404page.php` that acts as your entry point, sends out a `http_response_code(200);` and does what it further should do.

Off course you should remove any `index.php` from your `public_html` and not use any of the URLS that should be handled by the handler, so they will lead you to the `404page.php`.

(Let me know if this worked :). )